# ng-controller inside table does not work, why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<div ng-controller="xxxController" >                           
  <table>                       
    <tr ng-repeat="x in xxxx">
       <td>...
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

ng-controller tag out side any table, it works fine.

But below if ng-contoller tag are inside any table , ng-repeat would not work

```
<table>                                                             
  <div ng-controller="xxxController" >
    <tr ng-repeat="x in xxxx">
      <td>...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>    
</table>
```

Comment: the ultimate solution is Replace table element with div element. for example, you have nested tables, replace them with nested divs, this will always guarantee the div ng-controll="xxxx" work!

Answer (score 6):

`<div>` isn't a valid child element of `<table>`.  Because of this, the `<div ng-controller="xxxController">` would be moved outside the `<table>`, making the `<tr>` invalid, since they would also be outside the `<table>`.

In order for a `<div>` to be inside a `<table>` it would actually need to be a child of a `<td>`, which I think would break the structure you have.

As an alternative, it is a valid syntax to have the `ng-controller` on the `<table>` element itself:

```
<table ng-controller="xxxController">
  <tr ng-repeat'"x in xxx">
    <td>...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: <table ng-controller="xxxController">
  <tr ng-repeat'"x in xxx"> does not work, however, wrap div in td works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>       
        <div ng-controller="xxx" >

           <tr ng-repeat="x in xxxx">
              <td>...
              </td>
           </tr>

        </div> 

      </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I have test it, this works. div is not valid table element, so if div in side table, must be wrapped by a td element, for ng-controlller to work.

However in my case, with div in nested multi tables, even  wrap  would not work.

So the ultimate solution is Replace table element  with div element. for example, you have nested tables, replace them with nested divs, this will always guarantee the div ng-controll="xxxx" work!